# How to submit a HTML contact form using Node?

Tags: node.js, forms, email

I am having an issue trying to setup a contact form to be submitted using my node express app. I already have Nodemailer installed but I haven't used it before. Here is what I have so far..................

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(fs.readFileSync('./views/index.html', 'utf8'));

});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.body.mail == "" || req.body.subject == "") {
        res.send("Error: Email & Subject should not be Blank");
        return false;
    }

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", 
    secureConnection: true, 
    port: 465, 
        auth: {
            user: '',
            pass: ''
        }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: "Node Emailer - <email@gmail.com>",
    to: req.body.email, 
    subject: req.body.subject + " -",
    html: "<b>"+req.body.description+"<b>"
}
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        res.send("Email could not be sent due to error:" +error);
    }else {
        res.send("Email has been sent successfully");
    }
});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log("LISTENING!");
});
```

Contact Form

```
<form action='/' method='post' class='contact-form commentsblock'>

  <div>
       <label for='g52-name' class='grunion-field-label name'>Name<span>
       (required)</span></label>

       <input type='text' name='g52-name' id='g52-name' value='' 
       class='name'  
       required aria-required='true'/>

  </div>

   <div>
        <label for='g52-email' class='grunion-field-label email'>Email<span>
         (required)</span></label>
        <input type='email' name='g52-email' id='g52-email' value='' 
         class='email'  required aria-required='true'/>
   </div>

    <div>
        <label for='g52-website' class='grunion-field-label 
        url'>Website</label>
        <input type='text' name='g52-website' id='g52-website' value='' 
        class='url'  />
    </div>

<div>
        <label for='contact-form-comment-g52-comment' class='grunion-field-label textarea'>Comment<span>(required)</span></label>
        <textarea name='g52-comment' id='contact-form-comment-g52-comment' rows='20' class='textarea'  required aria-required='true'></textarea>
    </div>
    <p class='contact-submit'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='pushbutton-wide'/>
</form>
```

I haven't had much experience sending mail using Node. I have a one page site and all I want to do is to be able to send emails. How do I connect my form with Node?

Comment: Please define the problem/errors you have?

Comment: The issue was I had no idea how to connect my HTML form to my app.js file using app.post with Nodemailer. Everything has been resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields you check through `req.body` need to match the `name=""` attributes of your `<input>` and `<textarea>` HTML elements. It seems you don't fetch any of those values in your script, and sometimes arbitrarily look at either `req.body.email` or `req.body.mail`. If you `console.log(req.body)` on submit, you'll rather see something like:

```
{
  "g52-name": "...",
  "g52-email": "...",
  "g52-website": "...",
  "g52-comment": "..."
}
```

This is where your form content is.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var subject = req.body["g52-name"];
  var mail = req.body["g52-email"];
  var website = req.body["g52-website"];
  var description = req.body["g52-comment"];

  if (!subject || !mail) {
    res.send("Error: Email & Subject should not be Blank");
    return false;
  }

  // rest of email-sending code here
  // ...

}
```